# Pickling a very large text file, 12Gb

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to pickle a large text file, using the following code:

```
import pickle

file1=open('/home/mustafa/data/wiki.en.text','r')
obj=[file1.read()]
pickle.dump(obj,open('data.pkl','w'),2)
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
> ```

I think it might be a multiprocessing issue.

Comment: (1) It's obviously integer-limit related (but i don't know the exact source) (2) I don't see some good reason to do this (3) I think you should open the target-file in binary-mode (old python 2 docs: use binary if mode >= 1).

Comment: For data of 12GB, is pickle the right tool for the job? Or do you have to use it?

Comment: What version of the pickle protocol are you using? Note the [description of protocol 4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) (introduced in 3.4) includes "adds support for very large objects".

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It is certainly slower and more resource intensive than just re reading the file.

Comment: Do you actually have the need to read the entire English Wikipedia into memory at once? It might be a good idea to figure out what you want to do with it then come up with a less-stressful, likely-faster solution, e.g. put individual articles into your favorite database.

Comment: I'm using pickle protocol 2, yes my goal is to read the whole english wiki into memory and save it as a data.pkl file

Comment: Pickle is not the correct format for *one* text string. Protocol 2 is limited to 2GB. Why pickle?

Comment: Because I wanted to load my data.pkl file into another script. I have done this before but I just forgot. I was able to pickle a 12gb file

Comment: @Daniel Actually im not trying to pickle one string but rather wiki.en.text file

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of serialization pickle is not a good option. Even for cPickle, information > than 4Gb can be highly problematic. Have you think on using other alternatives like SQLite or HDF5?

Comment: Definitely considering SQlite now or HDF5 using hickle